# Image Source does not locate image file in working directory

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm new to WPF, facing a problem in locating an image file on a button.

It's not working when I put a relative path, as shown(Window1.xaml):

```
<Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,33,38,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Background="AliceBlue" OpacityMask="Cyan" Grid.Column="1" Click="button1_Click">
    <Image Source="Folder-icon.png"></Image>
</Button>
```

However, it's working when i put an absolute path:

```
<Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,33,38,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Background="AliceBlue" OpacityMask="Cyan" Grid.Column="1" Click="button1_Click">
    <Image Source="D:\Folder-icon.png"></Image>
</Button>
```

I try to describe my folder structure in picture.
[image: Folder Structure]

Hope someone can guide me to load the image to the button within the same workspace using relative path.

Comment: Currently I have to manually copy the image file to D:\, then only locate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare the Image.Source values for both cases, you will see in the cast that it does work the underlying Uri looks like:

```
file:///D:/Folder-icon.png
```

In the case where it does not work, the Image.Source value is null. The problem is that without the full path, WPF assumes it is a relative path to an embedded resource, not a file on disk.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) provides a detailed description of URIs. But you'd need to use something like the following to use relative paths.

```
pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Folder-icon.png
```

One other note, the default path will be in the `<Your Project Path\bin\Debug` folder, not the `<Your Property Path>` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The default path is in <bin>. It works after i changed to <Image Source=".\.\Folder-icon.png"></Image>

Comment: @wengseng This (".\.\Folder-icon.png") is not working for me.i tried with "pack://siteoforigin:,,,.\.\ /Picture/Folder.png" this format and fairly working.

Answer (score 1):

if is because you are not giving it correct path .Here is sample

```
/EmailScrapperWpf;component/Images/SearchDog.gif
```

it is like `/projectname;then path where your image is placed`

i think in your case it should be

```
 <Image Source="/WPF1;Folder-icon.png"></Image>
```

when you Select image from the properties when you select the `Image` and press F4 there source navigate to the image then see what path is displayed after selecting the image and you have to place that path in `Source=""`

Comment: It's still not working for me... Even I just added it into my Solution. I can see the "full path" and "File Name" after i press F4 on it. Either changing <Image Source="/WPF1;Folder-icon.png"></Image> or <Image Source="D:\Workspace\WPF1\WPF1\Folder-icon.png"></Image>, is not working...

Comment: ok do a test Drop a Image control from toolbox right click it and goto properties then select source it would open a new pop up window from where you would be able to goto the location of the image and select it.when you select it there will be path displayed in that window,Copy the full path and paste it in the Source tag of that image.and then press F5